# ディスプレイのカスタマイズでサイズの倍率を変更すると、スクリーンサイズが正しく取得できない

Tags: c#, windows

Windows10を使用しており、デスクトップのカスタマイズで、
『テキスト、アプリ、その他の項目のサイズを変更する』で倍率を上げています。

その状態で、Screen.Primry.Boundsでサイズを取得し、BmpクラスのSaveで
画面全体をキャプチャするコードを書いているのですが、保存された画像を
見てみると、実際の画面イメージより小さく、下と右が途切れてしまいます。

タイトルでは、ディスプレイのカスタマイズが原因かと思い込んで質問していますが、
ひょっとしたら他に原因があるのかもしれませんが、原因と対策をお教えください。

## 以下が、実際のソースです。

```
    private void captureFullScreen()
    {
        //Bitmapの作成
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        //Graphicsの作成
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        //画面全体をコピーする
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), bmp.Size);
        //解放
        g.Dispose();


        bmp.Save(this.path + @"\scr" + this.iCaptureCount + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

[image: Windows10側の設定画面]

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windowsには以前より[High DPI機能](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx#high_dpi_features_in_windows)が提供されています。この中でも特にWindows Vistaから提供されている**DPI仮想化機能**が影響しています。High DPIに未対応のアプリケーションの場合、Windows側で自動的に拡大するもので、その分、アプリケーションに対しては仮想化された小さな座標系のように振る舞います。これによってスクリーンの右下が切れてしまったのでしょう。

対策ですが、もちろんHigh DPI機能に対応することです。具体的な手順としては、プロジェクトに対して新規項目の追加でアプリケーションマニフェストを追加します。（その際、自動的にプロジェクトのプロパティのマニフェストの項に`app.manifest`が設定されます。）
追加された`app.manifest`ファイルには

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

の項目がコメントアウトされた形で書かれているはずですので、コメントを外すことで有効化してください。

古いVisual Studioでは一部の機能が提供されていませんので、その場合は、上記手順に相当するマニフェストを設定してください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。
いつも本当に助かります。
ズバリ一発で解決しました！！
また一つ為になりました。
また何かありましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

> タイトルでは、ディスプレイのカスタマイズが原因かと思い込んで質問していますが、
>   ひょっとしたら他に原因があるのかもしれませんが、原因と対策をお教えください。

そのとおりですが、一口には説明できませんので、とりあえずは下記URLを読んでみてください。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx
その他、「High DPI」「per monitor dpi」で検索するのも良いです。

どうしたいのかによりますが、manifestを付けると解決できるかも知れません。
こちらは「manifest dpiAware」で検索してみてください。